Angular Modular Federation with base-href for remote module in shell
I've 2 remote apps app1and app2 and a shell app myapp, since all the applications will be behind a proxy, each app is distinguished by  base-href i.e, /app1,/app2 and /myapp respectively. From app1 App1Module  is exposed as a remote which has app1.component which loads data from relative path of app1 from ./assets/config.json, the  code snippet to load the config.json is as shown below.
export class App1Component implements OnInit {
  message: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<any>('./assets/config.json').subscribe(v => (this.message = v.info));
  }
}

Now when I try to access the remote app directly using http://localhost:4201/app1/#/home, it is able to read the data from  config.json, where /app1 is baseHref
However  when I enable module federation and import App1Module to shell app 'myappand try to loadapp1.component, since  the relative path is provided myappadds its base href and tries to load the file  from http://localhost:4200/myapp/assets/config.jsoninstread ofhttp://localhost:4201/app1/assets/config.json`
Question: How to  retain the baseHref of imported remote module in shell when relative path is used in  remote module?
Example project can be found here
